# How to sort the string ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, json, bubble-sort

I am parsing the JSON array successfully. But I have a String which has numbers. So I want to sort all the data according to the numbers. I had been checked so many examples but I couldn't implement them in my code.So please help me.
Here is my code. here the "count" is the, string threw which I want to sort the data.

a.java

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler();
        String jsonStr = serviceHandler.makeServiceCall(
                JSONUrl.categoriesUrl, ServiceHandler.GET);
        Log.d("Response Categories:", ">" + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                categoriesJSONArray = jsonObj
                        .getJSONArray(JSONUrl.TAG_DATA);

                for (int i = 0; i < categoriesJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = categoriesJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    GridViewItem gridCategoriesItem = new GridViewItem();
                    gridCategoriesItem.setSlug(c
                            .getString(JSONUrl.TAG_CATEGORIES_SLUG));
                    gridCategoriesItem.setImage(c
                            .getString(JSONUrl.TAG_CATEGORIES_IMAGE));
                    gridCategoriesItem.setCount(c
                            .getString(JSONUrl.TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT));

                    mGridArrayCategories.add(gridCategoriesItem);

                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

GridViewItem.java

```
public class GridViewItem {
String image;
String slug;
String count;
String name;

public GridViewItem() {
    super();
}

public GridViewItem(String image, String slug, String count,
        String name) {
    super();
    this.image = image;
    this.slug = slug;
    this.count = count;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getSlug() {
    return slug;
}

public void setSlug(String slug) {
    this.slug = slug;
}

public String getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(String count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Comment: why would you even try and implement a bubble sort when java has Collections.sort() built in?!

Comment: WHy the heck are you using a bubble sort?  Unless you have a homework assignment that says "write a bubble sort", in which case you should do it yourself.

Comment: why bubble sort?? it is slow you know that it is O(n2)

Comment: I just want to sort the String, so any type of sort will work for me. Please help me

Comment: You might want to update your question to include possible inputs with their expected outputs.

Comment: I updated the question, now please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collection.sort()`.

for sorting any kind of `ArrayLsit` Object.

```
 Collections.sort(listOfStringArrays,new Comparator<String[]>() {
            public int compare(String[] strings, String[] otherStrings) {
                return strings[1].compareTo(otherStrings[1]);
            }
        });
```

Comment: It is also right method to sort the Array list...:)

Comment: you all of these code is working then why are you not accepting the answer, why are you waiting for more answer .

Comment: Hey I accepted your and others answers also @Lavekush Agrawal

Comment: Acceptance  mean click on right arrow in front of Answer, :) it will reward you +2 Reputation. if you accept answer. and it will helpful other as well.

Comment: Ohh my mistake, sorry ... I was thinking that if I will do upvote then then it will be accepted...:)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using bubble sort which is o(n2). 
You can use the native sort from the Collection class

**example:**

```
Collections.sort(mGridArrayCategories, new Comparator<GridViewItem>() {

    public int compare(GridViewItem s, GridViewItem s2) {
        return Integer.parseInt(s2.getCount()) - Integer.parseInt(s.getCount()); //this will sort your arrayList in decending order
    }
});
```

You need to parse your `string` to `int` so it will be sorted according to the `count`

Comment: yes @Rod_Algonquin it works but I want to sort this Array in decending order.

Comment: @AmitJayaswal switch the values in the compare method. Eddited